# duplicate key value violates unique constraint EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

this happens because I have

```
public class Language
    {
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column("native_name")]
        public string NtiveName { get; set; }
        [Column("code_1")]
        public string Code1 { get; set; }
        [Column("code_2")]
        public string Code2 { get; set; }
    }
      public class UserCreateModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        [Required]
        public string VerificationEmail { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool IsBusinessAccount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Language Language { get; set; }
    }
```

these two models and when try to create language it already exist ho can I prevent of creating language in languages table and only make just reference on it?

Comment: Either use [`Attach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-5.0) or query db for language and use returned entity.

Answer (score 0):

Create one-to many relations. Add Id and LanguageId properties to  UserCreateModel

```
public class UserCreateModel
    { 
         [Key]
         public int Id {get; set;}

        .....

        [Required]
        public int? LanguageId { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey(nameof(LanguageId))]
        [InverseProperty("UserCreateModels")]
        public Language Language { get; set; }
    }

public class Language
    {
        [Column("id")]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ....
        [InverseProperty(nameof(UserCreateModel.Language))]
        public virtual ICollection<UserCreateModel> UserCreateModels { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing Entities (Language) with View Models. (UserCreateModel)

UserCreateModel doesn't generally need a Language entity, or an object reference at all. This is probably something you would select from a drop-down list loaded from the Languages entities, in which case I'd normally suggest to just have a LanguageId in the UserCreateModel.

Then when you go to create a User entity from your UserCreateModel your code would look something like this:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{ 
    Language language = context.Languages.Single(x => x.LanguageId == userCreateModel.LanguageId);

    User user = new User
    {
         FirstName = userCreateModel.FirstName,
         LastName = userCreateModel.LastName,
         UserName = userCreateModel.UserName,
         Language = language
    };
    context.Users.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You may have what looks like an Language entity in your current view model, but when deserialized from your view, it is a completely new reference to data that *looks* like a Language entity. The DbContext knows nothing about it. You can work-around this by using `Attach` on the DbContext to associate the Language object with the DbContext, but if that DbContext has possibly already loaded/attached that Language reference you should always first check for an existing reference in the local cache and use that reference. In this case I'm assuming the DbContext is scoped outside of this code such as injected into the controller and managed by an IoC container:

```
Language language = context.Languages.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.LanguageId == userCreatedModel.Language.LanguageId);

if (language == null)
{
    context.Attach(userCreatedModel.Language);
    language = userCreatedModel.Language;
}
User user = new User
{
    FirstName = userCreateModel.FirstName,
    LastName = userCreateModel.LastName,
    UserName = userCreateModel.UserName,
    Language = language
};
context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The difference here is we first check the `.Local` DbSet cache for a reference to that language. This doesn't hit the database. If we don't find a language, we can attach the one provided and associate that one. Otherwise we will use the local one. This still isn't foolproof because we can still get exceptions if the Language passed into the call doesn't exist. (Deleted by another request, or tampered to be invalid)

If the User entity exposes a LanguageId FK property then you could forgo the loading of the Language and just use `LanguageId = userCreateModel.LanguageId` however by loading the Language you ensure that the User entity created (and possibly returned etc.) has a complete and valid Language reference set. After `SaveChanges`, any LanguageId FK property will be updated. If an invalid LanguageId is passed, by loading the language you will have an exception at that point pointing to that the language was not found. If you just set the LanguageId, you will get a FK constrain violation on User on `SaveChanges`.